# Make <TabPanel> content full width and hight as parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React with material-ui. I am using appbar with tabs and I want to be able when I pick some of the tabs the content of the tab to be full width and height.

Here is the sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-cookies-4dmf2?file=/src/App.js

[image]

As you can see the provided picture the content of the tab does not fill the whole page under the bar. How I can do it to fill it?

Comment: full width of ony selected tab or the whole tabslist of fullwidth with equal size tabs ?

Comment: full width of the selected tab only. I marked it with yellow where the content should be filling.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your marked div in your screenshot. You will find out the padding style is related to `MuiTabPanel-root`. On [Material's official website](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/), they introduced a few ways to override component's styles. Here is one of the ways you can do, to overide component's style by rule names. You can also find each component's rule name under **Component API** section on their website.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  tabPanelRoot: {
    padding: 0
  },
});
```

usage:

```
export default function App() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return(
        ...
        <TabPanel value="1" classes={{ root: classes.tabPanelRoot}}>
        ...
    )
}
```

See edited code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-morning-edx37?file=/src/App.js:1389-1450).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Updated code with useStyle hook.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import TabContext from "@material-ui/lab/TabContext";
import TabList from "@material-ui/lab/TabList";
import TabPanel from "@material-ui/lab/TabPanel";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import MonetizationOnIcon from "@material-ui/icons/MonetizationOn";
import ContactMailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ContactMail";
import AccessibilityIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Accessibility";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  appContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: "100vw",
    height: "100vh"
  },

  container: {
    display: "flex",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
  },
  panel: {
    width: "100%"
  }
});
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");
  const classes = useStyles();
  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <Box className={classes.appContainer}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <TabList
            variant="scrollable"
            onChange={handleChange}
            aria-label="simple tabs example"
          >
            <Tab label="Business Info" value="1" icon={<ContactMailIcon />} />
            <Tab label="Financial" value="2" icon={<MonetizationOnIcon />} />

            <Tab label="Participants" value="3" icon={<AccessibilityIcon />} />
          </TabList>
        </AppBar>

        <Box className={classes.container}>
          <TabPanel value="1" className={classes.panel}>
            <Box
              className={classes.container}
              style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
            >
              Content 1
            </Box>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value="2" className={classes.panel}>
            <Box style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }} className={classes.container} >Content 2</Box>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value="3" className={classes.panel}>
            <Box className={classes.container} style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}>Content 3</Box>
          </TabPanel>
        </Box>
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Here is the sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-voice-nih2s

Comment: It does not work. Look sandbox example as I implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

since the parent container is not of full height so, the tanpanel is not of full height. to make the tabpanel of full height pass a class to the root of the tabpanel. Pass the required height to `tabpanelRoot` class. (here I've neglected the height of the appbar)

```
export default function App() {
  const classes= useStyles()
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("1");

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <Box style={{height:'100%', background:'red'}}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <TabList
            variant="scrollable"
            onChange={handleChange}
            aria-label="simple tabs example"
          >
            <Tab label="Business Info" value="1" icon={<ContactMailIcon />} />
            <Tab label="Financial" value="2" icon={<MonetizationOnIcon />} />

            <Tab label="Participants" value="3" icon={<AccessibilityIcon />} />
          </TabList>
        </AppBar>

        <Box  style={{height:'100%', background:'red'}}>
          <TabPanel value="1" classes={{root:classes.tabpanelRoot}}>
            <Box style={{height:'100%', backgroundColor: "red" }}>Content 1</Box>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value="2" classes={{root:classes.tabpanelRoot}}>
            <Box style={{height:'100%', backgroundColor: "green" }}>Content 2</Box>
          </TabPanel>
          <TabPanel value="3" classes={{root:classes.tabpanelRoot}}>
            <Box style={{height:'100%', backgroundColor: "blue" }}>Content 3</Box>
          </TabPanel>
        </Box>
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
  );
}


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  tabpanelRoot: {
    padding:0,
    height: `calc(100vh - 52px)`
  },
}));
```

Here is the codesandbox link:- https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-noether-huxvz

Answer (score 0):

Tabs Height can be changed by .MuiTabs-root

```
const AntTab = styled((props: StyledTabProps) => (
  <Tab disableRipple {...props} />
  ))(() => ({

   **minHeight: '33px',
   maxHeight: '33px',**
   color: '#718296',
   fontFamily: 'Montserrat',

  }))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
import TabContext from '@mui/lab/TabContext';
import TabList from '@mui/lab/TabList';
import TabPanel from '@mui/lab/TabPanel';

export default function LabTabs() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('1');

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '100%', typography: 'body1' }}>
      <TabContext value={value}>
        <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}>
          <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
            <Tab label="Item One" value="1" />
            <Tab label="Item Two" value="2" />
            <Tab label="Item Three" value="3" />
          </TabList>
        </Box>
        <TabPanel sx={{pl: 1,pt:1}} value="1">Item One</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel sx={{pl: 1,pt:1}} value="2">Item Two</TabPanel>
        <TabPanel sx={{pl: 1,pt:1}} value="3">Item Three</TabPanel>
      </TabContext>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).